# Name Change Issue - Xcode trying to build from old file name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist, rename

I've changed the name of my project from "BSV22" to "BSVC". I renamed the project by going to project navigator and double-clicking the title. I accepted changes to all the file names. When I then run the project I get the following error:

```
could not read data from '/Users/bobpreston/Desktop/BSV22/BSV22/BSV22-Info.plist': 
The file “BSV22-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

it's pretty obvious why Xcode can't find the old file "BSV22-Info.plist"...because it was renamed when Xcode changed all the file names during the project rename. my question is why is Xcode still trying to build from that old file? it should be compiling from the new filename "BSVC-Info.plist" - and also how do i fix the issue? what else do i have to do?

Comment: Tried cleaning the project using Product>Clean

Comment: thank you jonogilmour but that did not change anything

Comment: Renaming a project is a little problematic. I've always just created a new project, copied the files over, then built again fresh. Tried hitting Product>Rebuild? That should do a fresh build.

Comment: I renamed it and then declined to allow Xcode to rename project content items...paradoxically, this worked. The files are still not the correct name but as far as the user sees the app has been renamed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your target Build Settings, check the `Packaging` section for the row called `Info.plist File`. Make sure it has been updated to use the new filename.

Comment: i'm now getting a new error; clang: error: no such file or directory: /Users/bobpreston/Desktop/BSV22/BSV22/BSV22-Prefix.pch. Using the same logic i changed info.plist preprocessor prefix file...but i'm still getting this new error.

Answer (score 0):

While renaming the project name from old name below are the steps:-

1) Changing the name from testing to testing123 and enter.
[image]

2) After that it will show the below window. So just click on the rename button
[image]

3) After that clean your build and run.

Comment: Hussain - that's what I did originally. Cleaning before running did not help. I still get this error; could not read data from '/Users/bobpreston/Desktop/BSV22/BSV22/BSV22-Info.plist': The file “BSV22-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.